# F# - Pattern Matching on boxed tuples

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

How can I pattern match on a boxed tuple? Or is there a better way to do something like this (simplified example):

```
open System.Drawing

let coerceColor a =
    match box a with
    | :? Color as c -> c
    | (:? int as r),(:? int as g),(:? int as b) -> Color.FromArgb(r,g,b)
    | _ -> failwith "Cannot coerce color"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let coerceColor a =
    match box a with
    | :? Color as c -> c
    | :? (int*int*int) as t -> t |> Color.FromArgb
    | _ -> failwith "Cannot coerce color"
```

But if I could change the design, I would rather use a DU or alternatively a static member with overloads.